# Is there any quick and easy way to upload a Google Doc from SAP?

Tags: sap, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-apps

We're creating a custom table in SAP comprising all of the information we need and the customer needs the report from this table uploaded to Google Docs. We do not use Business By Design. Is there any other quick and easy way to upload our report?

Comment: Which SAP software are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about SAP but the Documents List API has methods to programmatically upload a document to Google Docs: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/.

For instance, if you can export the SAP table as a csv file, that can be automatically converted into a Google Spreadsheet during the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with a no-programming required solution and install the Google Drive app on a machine with access to the files for automatic sync up to Google Drive:

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2374989

Answer (score 0):

suggest you take a look at the SAP Developer Network (SDN) / SAP Community Network (SCN) where there is a project called ABAP2GAPPS that has done this.

Note the ABAP2GAPPS example is a bit difficult to figure out (but you can learn a lot from it), and it also uses the OAuth2 'authorization code flow" OAuth2.0 flow/pattern, which requires an end-user 'consent' in an browser pop-up...so if you want to push up a file from ABAP automatically from a background job without end-user interaction then ABAP2GAPPS is not the full answer (but again, ABAP2GAPPS is a great example, suggest you look at it.)

We recently were able to achieve an interface from SAP ABAP to the Google Fusion Table API using OAuth2, with only about a 100 lines of ABAP...and the techniques we employed could be used on any of the Google API's...here's a link to the video:

[Link to YouTube video interface ABAP to Google API](http://youtu.be/uDgTxiR00cY)

hope you find this helpful